# dart arg parser implement default sub command

Tags: dart, args

I'm using the dart args package with a set of subcommands.

The command line syntax that I'm trying to implement is:

- dswitch beta switch
- dswitch beta install
- dswitch beta upgrade

'beta' is the command and there are three subcommands.

what I want to implement is a default sub command.

If the user runs:

dswitch beta

This should be the same as running:

dswitch beta switch

So how do I make 'switch' the default subcommand.

I'm currently getting the error:

UsageException (Missing subcommand for "dswitch beta".